# Retrieve .CSV from library with python requests/beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

beginner here. I'm trying to retrieve a .csv from python. After multiple .post and .get finally got to a point where i can download the file. In the web page in order to download the file there is a url which contains all files like this

https://example.com/storage/exports/443/

where there are multiple .csv files in the form of:

```
<a href="./2019-07-29%2007:59:26.csv">2019-07-29 07:59:26.csv</a>
```

I already have the href to the file I want, which is the last one with

```py
download=soup.find_all('a')[-1]
```

To download the file in the url i only need to click on the name of the file but i can't get around to do this with requests and beautifulsoup. My whole code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib

logind={'_token':'','email':'example@email','password':'123'}
#login
with requests.Session() as s:
    url='https://example.com'
    header={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'}
    r=s.get(url,headers=header)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    logind['_token']=soup.find('input',attrs={'name':'_token'})['value']
    r=s.post(url,data=logind,headers=header,verify=True)
    r=s.get('https://example.com/reports')
    r=s.post('https://example.com/reports2',data= {'id':'165'})
    r=s.post('https://example.com/reports/generate',data=dat)
    #multiple steps to generate the report


    r=s.get('https://example.com/storage/exports/443')
    #url where file is
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')
    download=soup.find_all('a')[-1]
    #href of file i need
```

Here's where I'm at, it would be only to retrieve the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to directly access the href with requests ?
It seems to be a relative path so you can take the original endpoint and append to it.

With pandas, you can directly read it and returns it (or even save it if you want)

so from your code

```
   ### what you have done before...
   download=soup.find_all('a')[-1]

   yourFile = requests.get(endpoint+download).text
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_csv(yourfile)
   df.to_csv('myreport.csv',index=false,sep='\t')
   return df
```

I hope this solve your issue.